# how to implement the tree sort algorithm in python? in binary search tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm try to implement a tree sort algorithm in python. 
This is the currently work I have done.
I'm not quite sure what a tree sort algorithm is and how to implement it.
Any help will be appreciate.
Thank you

```
 class BinTreeNode(object):

      def __init__(self, value):
           self.value=value
           self.left=None
           self.right=None


 def tree_insert( tree, item):
     if tree==None:
         tree=BinTreeNode(item)
     else:
         if(item < tree.value):
             if(tree.left==None):
                 tree.left=BinTreeNode(item)
             else:
                 tree_insert(tree.left,item)
      else:
          if(tree.right==None):
              tree.right=BinTreeNode(item)
          else:
              tree_insert(tree.right,item)
  return tree

def postorder(tree):
    if(tree.left!=None):
        postorder(tree.left)
    if(tree.right!=None):
       postorder(tree.right)
    print (tree.value)


def in_order(tree):
    if(tree.left!=None):
        in_order(tree.left)
    print (tree.value)
    if(tree.right!=None):
        in_order(tree.right)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  t=tree_insert(None,6);
  tree_insert(t,10)
  tree_insert(t,5)
  tree_insert(t,2)
  tree_insert(t,3)
  tree_insert(t,4)
  tree_insert(t,11)
  in_order(t)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question should be improved to meet our standards. What is wrong with the code you show? What is your exact question? What do you not understand about the documentation that explains tree sort? ([See Wikipedia's entry here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort)) Given the weaknesses of tree sort, why do you want to implement that rather than one of the other sorts, especially since Python has an excellent sort built in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close, however, `tree_insert` needs to be called as an attribute of the `left` or `right` member variables:

```
class SortTree:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.left = None
    self.value = value
    self.right = None
  def insert_val(self, _value):
    if _value < self.value:
       if self.left is None:
           self.left = SortTree(_value)
       else:
           self.left.insert_val(_value)
    else:
       if self.right is None:
          self.right = SortTree(_value)
       else:
          self.right.insert_val(_value)
  @classmethod
  def display(cls, _node):
     return list(filter(None, [i for b in [cls.display(_node.left) if isinstance(_node.left, SortTree) else [getattr(_node.left, 'value', None)], [_node.value], cls.display(_node.right) if isinstance(_node.right, SortTree) else [getattr(_node.right, 'value', None)]] for i in b]))


tree = SortTree(4)
for i in [5, 3, 1, 2, 8, 7, 4]:
  tree.insert_val(i)

print(SortTree.display(tree))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Edit: without `classmethod`:

```
class SortTree:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.left = None
    self.value = value
    self.right = None
  def insert_val(self, _value):
    if _value < self.value:
       if self.left is None:
         self.left = SortTree(_value)
       else:
         self.left.insert_val(_value)
    else:
       if self.right is None:
         self.right = SortTree(_value)
       else:
         self.right.insert_val(_value)

def display(_node):
   return list(filter(None, [i for b in [display(_node.left) if isinstance(_node.left, SortTree) else [getattr(_node.left, 'value', None)], [_node.value], display(_node.right) if isinstance(_node.right, SortTree) else [getattr(_node.right, 'value', None)]] for i in b]))

tree = SortTree(4)
for i in [5, 3, 1, 2, 8, 7, 4]:
  tree.insert_val(i)

print(display(tree))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: what can i do if i dont want to use @classmethod?

Comment: @LeeCardo the `classmethod` is merely to check that the elements are indeed sorted. It is not necessary otherwise.

Comment: but i delete the @classmethod an i get an error code            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 26, in <module>
TypeError: display() missing 1 required positional argument: '_node'             what i can do instead of it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how to print out the tree

Comment: @LeeCardo How should the tree be printed? As nested lists, or strings?

Comment: what about in string? what does those "None" mean?

Comment: @LeeCardo The `None` values are the `left` or `right` class attributes not storing a `SortTree` node.

Comment: Can it print out the tree as same as the output from classmethod

Comment: Appreciate your help

Comment: sorry for disturb. I'm still not quite understand what did u do under            def display(_node)        can u do it in simple way? And explain this?

Comment: what I mean is can you define display() in the same way you use to define insert_val() ? thank you

Comment: it can help me to understand how to do this

Comment: display method is unreadable, not sure why people write code like this. I appreciate code-golfing when it makes sense and is nicely implemented, but not when explaining an algorithm to users asking questions on stackoverflow.